# Google Cloud VPN configuration, tunnel close automatically

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform

I have some VPN's tunnels established with some partners, all of them are working just fine, however there is a new partner which I know it has a cisco router to which I need to connect, the VPN was established correctly, but.. they have a security policy that when the VPN is not in use the router close the tunnel until is required again, because of that when I try to reach the private IP at my end, is not accepting any connections because the tunnel is closed, but in Google the VPN shows connected and the logs is not telling any errors, we did a test with them, in which they ping the server to force the tunnel opening, so we know it gets open when is required, but because Google won't let me modified much it seems is not trying to open the tunnel from my end, hmm one thing is that I can do ping, but not connect to any other port, until them at they side do a ping that force the tunnel to open again

So am asking for tips or advice on how to handle these type of situations, is possible to keep it open?, is there is something I can configure at Google ends? sadly I can't find info form Google, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could launch a long time running ping (ping  -t) from a GCE instance on Google Cloud Platform side on the VPC network where the tunnel connects to towards an IP address in your on premise network.
Another option would be to launch a ping command from the GCE instance on a periodic manner via the crontab.
Ideally, if the GCE instance has a public external IP address configured, you will be able to connect to it via SSH and launch the ping command.
That way the tunnel traffic would come up.

I see no other way, as it is not possible connect to the cloud VPN gateway, to launch any command from the gateway itself.

I hope this helps.